# Can you find a plain aneloid?

Tags: universal-algebra

I defined an "aneloid" to be a set endowed with two operations, adition and multiplication, with multiplication being distributive BOTH sides in relation to adition.

I tried to find an example of "plain" aneloid, a such one that adtion and multiplication doesn't have any property of an abelian group, i. e. both operations should be not commutative, not associative, not have a neutral element (I'm not taking account of another properties like cancellation and idempotents).

I tried many finite and infinite examples but seems to me that the exigence of both sides distributivity implies at least one property of group (if you want distributivity by one side only is very easy to find examples).

I tried to proof by absurd if there exists a plain aneloid then one side of distributivity is violated, but I do not have sucess.

My question is: do you know an example of plain aneloid? Or a plain aneloid violates the both side distributivity?

Comment: What do you mean by "distributivity both sides"?

Comment: @A.P. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Distributive_property#Definition).

Comment: Did you try the bundle "Mace4/Prover9" by Bill McCune? It furnishes counterexamples to such conjectures in a matter of seconds.

Comment: If we take in the set {a,b}, a*a=b, a*b=a, b*a=b, b*b=a, as adition and multiplication at same time, it is not comutative, not associative, does not have neutral elemente, is not right-distributive over itself, but is left-distributive over itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\begin{array}{c|cccc}
\diamond & 0 & a & b & 1\\
\hline
0 & 0 & 1 & a & b \\
a & b & a & 1 & 0\\
b & 1 & 0 & b & a \\
1 & a & b & 0 & 1\\ 
\end{array}$$

$\diamond$ is not commutative: $a\diamond b =1\neq 0 = b\diamond a$

$\diamond$ is not associative: $(a\diamond a)\diamond b= a \diamond b = 1\neq 0 = a\diamond 1 = a\diamond(a\diamond b)$

Take any finite field $\mathbf{F}$ of order $p^n\geq 3$ and a generator $a\in F$ such that $a\neq0,1$. Define an operation $\diamond$ on $F$ by $x\diamond y=a\cdot x + (1-a)\cdot y$. According to Theorem 2.6 in Jezek and Kepka's paper "Atoms in the lattice of varieties of distributive groupoids," $\diamond$ distributes over itself.

Therefore if $A=\{0,1,a,b\}$, then $\mathbf{A}=(A,\diamond,\diamond)$ is a 'plain aneloid.'

Also, the word plain has already been used for algebraic structures: see [here](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01229959).

Comment: Thanks! My teacher told me that with four elements it will be encountered...

Comment: Now I'm wondering, there exsists an infinite plain aneloid?